Чем отличается pushl от push
есть вот такая ассемблерная вставка в функции:
void func(void*, int, int, int, int, int, void*, int offset){
...
__asm__ __volatile__ (
"pushl %%ebp,\n\t"            // save EBP register
"movl 0x24(%%ebp), %%ebp\n\t" // 0x24 - "offset" param
"int $0x40\n\t"
"popl %%ebp" // restore EBP register
...
::"a"(65)
...
);

можете объяснить почему используется именно pushl, а не push
и про \n\t
ps: в ассемблере не почти ничего не понимаю

Ничем, это просто указание размера операнда в AT&T синтаксисе.

l - означает, что на стек ложится 4-х байтное значени ССЫЛКА
А просто push это из Intel'овского ассемблера ССЫЛКА
Ещё ССЫЛКА
\n\t - спецсимволы для обозначения непечатаемых символов: конец строки и таб.

Можно добавить, что \n добавляют в конце строк для того чтобы ассемблерная вставка была правильным текстом (каждая команда на отдельной строке) для ассемблера
